# Best Testing Practices for WiX / Windows Installer

Tags: windows, testing, wix, windows-installer, custom-action

According to WiX Documentation, convenient Custom Actions are offered in order to help the testing phase:

[WixExitEarlyWithSuccess](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/wixexitearlywithsuccess.html)

[WixFailWhenDeferred](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/wixfailwhendeferred.html)

Is there any problem (or bad practice) with including these custom actions in the final MSI that is going to be delivered to end-users?

Otherwise, what strategy for testing would you recommend? (ie: Having two MSI, one for testing and another for production?)

Any (best) practices you might have for testing WiX / Windows Installer are welcome.

Comment: Always always use virtual machines and start from a clean system each time.

Comment: I just found out the following link: [Tao of Windows Installer - Testing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2006/07/28/681358.aspx)

Take a look, it's really useful.